# iOS8 Swift "AnyObject" is not identical to "String" error when trying to access dictionary - how to suppress?

Tags: collections, casting, compiler-errors, swift, ios8

I'm working in Objective-C to Swift mixed project and am seeing the following error message when trying to retrieve an object that I know to be a string: "AnyObject" is not identical to "String".

I really don't want to explicitly specify every single time what I'm getting out of a collection. **How can I supress compiler errors like this and let me work with anyobject like Objective-C id types?**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you make your `dataSource.array` into a `[[String:String]]`, or whatever it actually is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let dict = (dataSource.array[indexPath.row]) as NSDictionary
cell.titleLabel.text = dict.objectForKey("done")! as String
```

**EDIT:**

Safer solution is to check if you can cast object from dictionary to string

```
if let dict = dataSource.array[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary {
    cell.titleLabel.text = (dict.objectForKey("done") as? String) ?? ""
}
```

Comment: I found that I get a warning unless I wrap the right side of equation in parens:  cell.titleLabel.text = (dict["done"]! as String)